# I cant read an Attribute from a XML/RSS on ActionScript 3 (flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

very simple question, i have this: (only a part of the complete rss file)

```
 <item>
      <title>Ok, de regalo de San Valentin me pueden dar un viaje a Playa del Carmen! Digo, entre todos lo pagan! No?? #So&#241;arNoCuestaNada</title>
      <link>http://twitter.com/glenyvalente/statuses/37202068301295616</link>
      <description>Ok, de regalo de San Valentin me pueden dar un viaje a &lt;b&gt;Playa&lt;/b&gt; del Carmen! Digo, entre todos lo pagan! No?? &lt;a href=&quot;http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23So%C3%B1arNoCuestaNada&quot; onclick=&quot;pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, 'result_type', 'recent', 3);pageTracker._trackPageview('/intra/hashtag/#So&#241;arNoCuestaNada');&quot;&gt;#So&#241;arNoCuestaNada&lt;/a&gt;</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 14 Feb 2011 17:30:38 +0000</pubDate>
      <guid>http://twitter.com/glenyvalente/statuses/37202068301295616</guid>
      <author>glenyvalente@twitter.com (Gleny Valente)</author>
      <media:content type="image/jpg" width="48" url="http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1225905511/S5030401_normal.JPG" height="48"/>
      <google:image_link>http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1225905511/S5030401_normal.JPG</google:image_link>
      <google:location>Venezuela</google:location>
      <twitter:metadata>
        <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
      </twitter:metadata>
    </item>
```

And i read `<title>` and `<pubDate>` using:

```
function rssLoaded(evt:Event):void {
    rssXML = XML(rssLoader.data);
    for(var item:String in rssXML.channel.item) {
    fechas.push(rssXML.channel.item[item].pubDate.substr(0, 16));
    titulos.push(rssXML.channel.item[item].title);
    trace(rssXML.channel.item[item].media:content.attributes.url);
    total=total+1;
    }
    trace(total);
}
```

but, `trace(rssXML.channel.item[item].media:content.attributes.url);` is always empty, so how can i read the attribute **url** from the tag `<media>` ??? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://help.adobe.com/...](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#attribute_identifier)

@ attribute identifier

Usage

`myXML.@attributeName`

> Identifies attributes of an XML or XMLList object. For example, myXML.@id identifies attributes named id for the myXML XML object. You can also use the following syntax to access attributes: myXML.attribute("id"), myXML["@id"], and myXML.@["id"]. The syntax myXML.@id is recommended. To return an XMLList object of all attribute names, use @*. To return an attribute with a name that matches an ActionScript reserved word, use the attribute() method instead of the @ operator.

```
var myXML:XML = 
    <item id = "42">
        <catalogName>Presta tube</catalogName>
        <price>3.99</price>
    </item>;

trace(myXML.@id); // 42
```

In your case:

```
trace(rssXML.channel.item[item].media:content.@url);
```

Comment: hello, that gave me an error: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 19 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon.

Comment: It is problem with namespace. You should use following syntax: `var media:Namespace = new Namespace(rssXML.namespace("media")); trace(rssXML.media::content.@url);`

Comment: [http://help.adobe.com/...](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#namespace())

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.attribute("url")` I think `.attributes()` are for all [attributes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#attributes%28%29) within that element.

Try Reading [Traversing XML structures](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html)